# Provisioning Sitecore environment using Solr connection string

Tags: sxa, azure

We are using Sitecore 9 Update 2 and SXA 1.7.1.

We are provisioning Sitecore environment using Solr connection string through ARM template in Azure PaaS environment.

We need `solrSupportSxaMsDeployPackageUrl` package in order to execute this.

Could anyone help us where we can get this package to download?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can download WDP packages from SXA download page from "Download options for Azure AppService" section:
https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Accelerator/17/Sitecore_Experience_Accelerator_17_Update1.aspx

[image]

Follow documentation in Azure Quickstart Templates github repo provided by Sitecore:
- https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore-Azure-Quickstart-Templates/tree/master/SXA%201.7.1/xp0

Path to wdp package should be in `modules` parameter in `solrSupportSxaMsDeployPackageUrl`:

```
{
    "name": "sxa",
    "templateLink": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Sitecore/Sitecore-Azure-Quickstart-Templates/master/SXA/xp0/azuredeploy.json",
    "parameters":
    {
      "cmSxaMsDeployPackageUrl": "<URL of the WDP file *_sxa.scwdp.zip>",
      "speMsDeployPackageUrl": "<URL of the WDP file *_spe.scwdp.zip>",
      "solrSupportSxaMsDeployPackageUrl" : "<URL of the WDP file SXA Solr Support *.scwdp.zip> Can be empty",
      "templateLinkAccessToken" : "Access token for the template if stored under the Azure storage. Otherwise should be empty string"
    }
  }
```

There are more repos for each specific setup (xm, xp, xp0):
- https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore-Azure-Quickstart-Templates/tree/master/SXA%201.7.1